# Dynamically Sized UITableView From UITextField Input

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

What I am looking for is similar to what is in the iOS Contacts application: when adding emails, for example, there is initially just one UITextField. However, when you start typing, another UITextField is added below, etc so you can add an arbitrary number of rows, and delete rows if you wish.

How can I implement something similar, with a normal UITableView? I have added a prototype UITableViewCell with a UITextField in it, but I am not sure how to handle the dynamic sizing behavior.

Comment: In the contacts app it looks like another cell is added, not simply a label. This should be doable, to add to a cell in the table and redisplay based on editing a cell.

Comment: Right, by size I meant number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a UITableView is a good approach, i believe. Think of dynamically adding Cells to your table. Use the following methods of UITableView in this sequence:

- (void)beginUpdates
- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
- (void)endUpdates

Answer (score 0):

Follow the UITableView class reference.
There you can change the height of table cell by [table reloadData] method.
and you can get the number of lines from UITextField by its method. Check the UITextfield class reference.

It's good to refer ClassReference before start on it.

Thanks.